# Activity поверх keyguard и разблокировка экрана

Tags: java, android

Есть фоновый сервис, который бродкастом "слушает" сервер. Когда с сервера приходит звонок, срабатывает метод:

```
CallActivity1.start(this,
                        qbrtcSession.getConferenceType(),
                        qbrtcSession.getOpponents(),
                        qbrtcSession.getUserInfo(),
                        Consts.CALL_DIRECTION_TYPE.INCOMING);
```

Где CallActivity1 — одна из активностей приложения, но не главная.
Принимает она:

```
public static void start(Context context, QBRTCTypes.QBConferenceType qbConferenceType,
                             List<Integer> opponentsIds, Map<String, String> userInfo,
                             Consts.CALL_DIRECTION_TYPE callDirectionType){
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, CallActivity1.class);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.CALL_DIRECTION_TYPE_EXTRAS, callDirectionType);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.CALL_TYPE_EXTRAS, qbConferenceType);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.USER_INFO_EXTRAS, (Serializable) userInfo);
        intent.putExtra(Consts.OPPONENTS_LIST_EXTRAS, (Serializable) opponentsIds);
        if (callDirectionType == Consts.CALL_DIRECTION_TYPE.INCOMING) {
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
        }
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
```

И в onCreate прописано :

```
KeyguardManager.KeyguardLock lock = ((KeyguardManager) getSystemService(Activity.KEYGUARD_SERVICE)).newKeyguardLock(KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    PowerManager powerManager = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE));
    PowerManager.WakeLock wake = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, "TAG");

    lock.disableKeyguard();
    wake.acquire();

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
            | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);
```

По моей логике при звонке окно активности должно открываться всегда, оно почти так и работает, но попеременно. При разблокированном экране активность ВСЕГДА запускается, при screen_off иногда, а если на screen_off еще и стоит keyguard, то вообще никогда не срабатывает, или может появиться и через мнгновенье закрыться.

Пошаговое выполнение показало что как только активность появилась, сразу же сработал onStop, и почему так — неизвестно.

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно использовать системный тип активити чтобы оно отображалось поверх всего.
Для этого нужно добавить в манифест следующие разрешение:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

и установить для Activity тип `TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`.

```
MyActivity.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY);
```

Тогда Activity будет поверх вообще всего, включая экран блокировки. 
Также вам не нужно будет разблокировать телефон программно ( lock.disableKeyguard(); - не нужен )